# Visual Studio 2017: Turn off all "Based on your project..." recommendations

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, ide, visual-studio-2017

I started noticing these recommendations as shown below in VS 2015, and they seem to be growing in number and frequency in VS 2017.  Although I click the "Don't show again" button, these recommendations continue to pop up.  Does anyone have a simple means of turning these suggestions off entirely?

> "Based on your project, we have identified extensions you may find
>   helpful"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menu: Tools > Options

Options tree: Text editor > HTML > Advanced.

Set `Identify helpful extensions` to `false`

[image]